# For Purchase software in software center is empty

Tags: 11.10

For Purchase software in software center is empty. All other software are fine.  Using ubuntu 11.10 US  no proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always empty in Beta versions. Or at least it was empty in 11.04 and now in 11.10. When we move closer to the release date Canonical will populate it.

Comment: How come on my laptop it is not empty? that's why I asked.  But thanks for answer.

Comment: Is your laptop updated?. It's empty in Betas not before.